Excel Office Script to remove rows with highlighted cells
I'm looking for help with an office script that will remove any rows from my table that contain highlighted cells. I tried using the recorder to filter rows with highlighted cells from one of my columns, but the recorder returns 'This action is not yet recordable.' So I am stumped as to how to proceed. Has anyone written a successful script that does the same?
Script so far:
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let conditionalFormatting: ExcelScript.ConditionalFormat;
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    // Create preset criteria from range B:B on selectedSheet
    conditionalFormatting = selectedSheet.getRange("B:B").addConditionalFormat(ExcelScript.ConditionalFormatType.presetCriteria);
    conditionalFormatting.getPreset().getFormat().getFont().setColor("#9C0006");
    conditionalFormatting.getPreset().getFormat().getFill().setColor("#FFC7CE");
    conditionalFormatting.getPreset().setRule({criterion: ExcelScript.ConditionalFormatPresetCriterion.duplicateValues,});
}

After this, I need to filter out the rows that contain the highlighted cells. Or even deleting those rows works as well.
Thank you!
I tried using the recorder, but received a message saying the action is not yet recordable.


Record Actions doesn't work with Filter by Cell Color operation.
Use filterOn: ExcelScript.FilterOn.cellColor to filter the duplicated cells.

function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    // get data range on Col B
    let dataRng = selectedSheet.getRange("B:B").getIntersection(selectedSheet.getUsedRange())
    // apply C.F.
    let condFormat = dataRng.addConditionalFormat(ExcelScript.ConditionalFormatType.presetCriteria);
    let cfFormat = condFormat.getPreset().getFormat()
    cfFormat.getFont().setColor("#9C0006");
    let colorToFilter = "#FFC7CE";
    cfFormat.getFill().setColor(colorToFilter);
    condFormat.getPreset().setRule({ criterion: ExcelScript.ConditionalFormatPresetCriterion.duplicateValues });
    // apply autofilter
    selectedSheet.getAutoFilter().apply(selectedSheet.getRange("B1"));
    // filter duplicated cells with filling color
    let filterCriteria = {
        filterOn: ExcelScript.FilterOn.cellColor,
        color: colorToFilter
    };
    selectedSheet.getAutoFilter().apply(dataRng, 0, filterCriteria);
    let visRng = dataRng.getResizedRange(-1,0).getOffsetRange(1,0);
    // highlight duplicated rows with Green
    visRng.getEntireRow().getFormat().getFill().setColor("#00FF00");
    // remove duplicated rows
    visRng.getEntireRow().delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.up);
    // Toggle auto filter on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getAutoFilter().remove();
}


Thank you. I am getting an error message on line 13: 'dataRng.getAutoFilter is not a function'. Any suggestions?

dataRng.getAutoFilter is not from the snippet on my answer. The syntax is incorrect. It should be <SheetObject>.getAutoFilter.

Right. I'm not sure how I confused that. The error message is actually, "Line 13: AutoFilter apply: The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format."

I've tesed the code w/o issues. Please edit your post and upload a screenshot to show the layout of sheet.
